Macro in Basic for LibreOfficeWriter: place a new textFrame relatively to an existing bookmark
I have a Writer document, that has bookmarks (It's a theater play, the bookmarks are the number of each verse).
I'd like to make the verse numbers visible, in order to do that, for each bookmark I create a new textFrame, and its text is the bookmark name.
The only issue I have is placing the textFrame: in my case I want the text frame anchored relatively to the anchor. I tried a few things, but no joy.
Where I am at now:
Here is my macro:
Sub CreateTextFramesForBookmarks()
    Dim document As Object
    Dim bookmarks As Object
    Dim bookmark As Object
    
    document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    bookmarks = ThisComponent.Bookmarks

    For Each bookmark In bookmarks
    
        Dim anchor As Object
        anchor = bookmark.getAnchor
        
        Dim textFrame As Object
        textFrame = ThisComponent.createInstance( "com.sun.star.text.TextFrame" )
        textFrame.Width = 6000  
        
        ThisComponent.Text.insertTextContent(anchor, textFrame, false )
     
        textFrame.Text.String = bookmark.getName()
    Next bookmark
End Sub

I created the following document, that has a 3 bookmarks : 
This is what my macro manages to do: 
I must be doing something right because the textFrames are vertically aligned with their corresponding bookmarks.
What I wish to achieve :

Have the textFrames positionned relatively to the bookmark (as if anchored to character)

Be able to set the textFrames' horizontal and vertical position relatively to the bookmarks

Have the textFrames wrapped "through" the existing text.


Thanks for reading!
